# Rename file with back-reference and date-timestamp

Tags: powershell, rename, backreference

I can't get this to work:

```
Get-Item 'foo.txt' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace $_.basename, ((Get-Date -format 'yyyyMMdd.hhmm') + '-' + $1)}
```

the output is **20170323.0329-.txt** and the output I want would be **20170323.0329-foo.txt**. I've done backreference before, but not with rename-item, and I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *don't* need a regex here. Just use a *format string*:

```
Get-Item 'foo.txt' | Rename-Item -NewName {('{0:yyyyMMdd.hhmm}-{1}' -f (Get-Date), $_.BaseName)}
```

Comment: tunnel vision.. get so used to using regex in everything else I forgot.. thanks

Comment: Dont use BaseName but Name, because he want keep extension ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just do it

```
$file="test2.txt"
Rename-Item $file ('{0:yyyyMMdd.hhmm}-{1}' -f (Get-Date), $file)
```